# Global $pager_total_items replacment

Tags: drupal-8

I updated a website to Drupal 8.9.6 version. I saw that the global variable $pager_total_items was used, but is deprecated since D8.8.0.
So, I'm looking for an alternative to retrieve the total items of the pager.
This was used on a **Search API page**.

The old code looks like this :

```
$variables['count_results']     = empty($GLOBALS['pager_total_items']) ? 0 : $GLOBALS['pager_total_items'][0];
```

And now, looking this change record : https://www.drupal.org/node/2779457 I try to replace this like this :

```
/** @var \Drupal\Core\Pager\PagerManager $pagerManager */
$pagerManager = \Drupal::service('pager.manager');
dpm($pagerManager->getPager());
```

This renders nothing in the dpm(), so no Pager was found. It appears that Search API doesn't use a Pager...

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$pager = \Drupal::service('pager.manager')->getPager();
$count_results = $pager->getTotalItems();
```